# Top-Left White Border in WebBrowser When Using iFrame

Tags: html, .net, iframe

I'm attempting to embed a Google map iFrame in my application:

```
    Dim Map As String

    Map = "<html>" & _
            "<body>" & _
                "<div style =""overflow:auto;"">" & _
                    "<iframe " & _
                        "Width = """ & webMap.Width & """ " & _
                        "Height = """ & webMap.Height & """ " & _
                        "frameBorder=""0"" " & _
                        "style=""border:0;"" " & _
                        """padding-top:0;"" " & _
                        """margin-top:0;"" " & _
                        """border-top:none;"" " & _
                        "src=""https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=[Key]&q=[Address]""" & _
                        "allowfullscreen>" & _
                    "</iframe>" & _
                "</div>" & _
            "</body>" & _
        "<html>"

    webMap.DocumentText = Map
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0IYn.jpg)

The map always comes with a white margin at the top and on the left-hand side. I've tried setting the margins on the control to '0', and, as you can see, I've tried adjust the borders/margins of the frame. What's causing this? Browsing to ordinary web addresses produces no border.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could inspect CSS of the gmap iframe. 
Sometimes, there's a margin that you could overwrite in your CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Set an ID to your div `<div style =""overflow:auto;"">`, like "mapMap" (example).
After doing this, you can handle your css:

```
#mapMap > iframe{
   border: 0;
}
```

here's the jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/curcif/30dkod1t/